# Is it possible to run nested VMs with in VMWare Workstation without Intel VT-x?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-workstation, intel-vt-x

I need to fiddle with ESXi inside a VMware workstation 9 Virtual machine but my old Intel Core 2 Duo T6400 does not have Intel VT-x hardware assist technology!

Is there any mean to run a bare-metal hypervisor in a virtual machine without Intel VT-x (with older versions of VMware Workstation or ESXi hypervisor for exemple)?

Comment: Have you tried it? For the sake of a small ISO, it's got to be worth a shot.

Comment: Yes I tried with ESXi 5 in VMWare Workstation 9 : doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. For running 32-bit virtual machines you need to have Intel VT-x / AMD-V support at least. For 64-bit machines, you need [SLAT/EPT (Intel) or RVI/NPT (AMD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Level_Address_Translation) as well.  Nested ESXi hypervisor should be working since VMware Workstation 7. For more details, I would recommend you to check  [Installing ESXi 5.x in VMware Workstation](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2034803) knowledge-base article.

Comment: For clarification I run VMWare workstation 9 and nesting virtual machines requires Intel-VT-x.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was confusing a bit. Rewritten ...

Answer (score -2):

You can't run ESXi inside VM.
But you can run VM inside OS inside VM on the ESXi.

Comment: It is actually possible : [link](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2034803)

Comment: @jscott It is, and it's perfectly possible from within VMware Workstation, too.